# Cannot install ibm db2 express-c V10.1 on mac

Tags: xcode, macos, db2

I am new to db2 10.1, i have used an older version of it before so, i am unfamiliar with the installation.
I searched online how to install it and followed this site http://programmingzen.com/files/db2onmac.pdf
but when i try to run 'db2setup' inside expc i get these errors.(i uploaded it to google drive so it would be easier to download and view externally)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdZNdArow5yRkhlMzlIdTFsemc/view?usp=sharing

I noticed that all these errors are from Xcode; i have Xcode installed and updated to the latest version , and yes i have also tried to use 'db2_install', it gave me the same errors but after them it installed normally in '/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1', i also used sudo before each one of them, so when i gave up i searched the internet, but i couldn't find an answer, then i tried to delete it using 'db2_deinstall' but it didn't work at all, so i don't know how to reinstall.

Right now i have 'IBM' folder, but i don't even know how to start it to see if it works or not, and i don't know how to open 'db2 first steps' or where is it.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: i am trying to install db2 express-c and the only version available for mac is 10.1 .

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying DB2-Express-C V10.1 on a Mac, then why not try instead
the "DB2 Developer Community Edition" which is supported on "Mac OS: 10.12 (Sierra) +", a free download. It contains DB2 V11.1.2.2 at today's date.

If you need V10.1 for some reason, check out the [IBM express-c forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000805&ps=25) which also has some troubleshooting questions regarding Mac support.